# Why is there no option to choose codepage 65001 (UTF-8) as a default codepage in console window?

Tags: windows-7, console

I can change codepage 950 (my computer's default) into codepage 65001 (UTF-8):

```
chcp 65001
```

[image: Properties]

But why is there no option to choose codepage 65001 as a default codepage in
console?

[image: Default]

Is it able to add codepage 65001 as an option?

Comment: I don’t get the code-page fields *at all*. `:-|`

Comment: Incidentally, people have reached behind the dialog box and set the value to 65001 directly. This usually results in a non-booting Windows so don't do it.

Answer (score 4):

Several ways, I think

- Run cmd.exe with shortcut, "cmd.exe /k chcp 65001".
- If using emulators like ConEmu or Console - specify the same as startup command.
- Modify your registry

  ```
  [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]
  "AutoRun"="chcp 65001"
  ```

Comment: Is there any side-effects of doing this apart from making UTF-8 characters look correct?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai It messes up vim, at least in ConEmu.

Comment: Mess up in vim does not relate to ConEmu. It just shows what console application prints. But when you are working in ConEmu, you may use [environment variables](http://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuEnvironment.html#ConEmuCpCvt).

Answer (score 1):

Browse to this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage
```

and change `OEMCP` to `65001`. Then restart. With this fix, if you are using
Consolas font, it seems to lock PowerShell into a small font size. `cmd.exe`
still works fine. As a workaround, you can use Lucida Console, or I switched
to Cascadia Mono:

https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code